# Use manager classes to save collection of class

Tags: c#, class, oop

I want to save many different master data lists. Every master data list have a undefined number of attributes. Every Attribute got some properties. What is the best practise to save this data construct?

I was thinking alot, but I think my "idea" isn't that good.

```
- ManagerRoot                  (class)
  - MasterDataManager          (class)
    - MasterData               (class)
      -> Name                  (propertie)
      -> ID                    (propertie)
      - AttributeManager       (class)
        - Attribute            (class)
          -> Name              (propertie)
          -> AdresseType       (propertie)
          -> Prefix            (propertie)
```

I read often that manager classes are evil. Currently I would add a method like `getAttribute()` to the `AttributeManager` class. But when I don't use any manager class, where I have to add methods like this then?

Maybe you can give me some examples. Thanks!

Comment: I don't really understand your problem. What are `master data lists`?

Comment: Your question hints at a misunderstanding of OOP. It's not only about what data and relationships a class has, but about the responsibility. Always start your design with the responsibility of a class, what data (state) it holds and what collaborations it has with other classes will emerge from your design to fulfill that responsibility. DO NOT start thinking in terms of data and relationships when designing classes.